# How to fix messy data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have imported a data set (.xlsx file) into a dataframe. Unfortunately, this has produced many NaN entries. I believe that this is caused by problems in the delimiter. For example the data set comes out as:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4
_______    _______    _______    _______
1          Pink;1;True   NaN     NaN
3          NaN           NaN     NaN
```

Does anyone know any packages that could solve this or what the root of the problem is? I am new to R.

**EDIT**: What the xlxs file looks like:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4
_______   _______   _______   _______
1         Pink      1         True
3         Blue      2         True
```

**Thank you**

Comment: Hi. Perhaps you could show an example of what the data looks like in the .xlsx file. Also, what code have you used to import the data?

Comment: You .xlsx file is delimited? If you use functions that import .txt/.csv files you typically have a variable where you can define your delimiter (if the function doesn't recognize it automatically), however .xlsx files should normally not be delimited

Comment: @WietsedeVries I'm aware that it is usually not. Its the fact that the <Na> values usually begin after what looks like to delimited data gone wrong (Pink;1;True).

Comment: So have you used a package specifically designed to import `.xlsx` files? For example `readxl`

Comment: @MarkDavies yes, I've used read_excel. I don't think this is an R dependent problem, as I've tried using the Python package Pandas to which also produced the same problem. What is strange is that the excel file itself seems relatively clean, which each column organized.

Comment: Can you show us how the .xlsx looks like by editing the original question?

Comment: @WietsedeVries It has been edited now.

Comment: a possible workaround could be to load it into a spreadsheet programm (Excel,libre,etc) and export as .csv then read in the csv into R.  also change the to sep=";" or ", " and see what changes

Comment: @user12256545 unfortunately I have tried both those solutions. Same problem with a csv file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.